# Why don't the buttons in Flutter Web have a margin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have the following code:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Boton 1'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Boton 2'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Boton 3'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Why on mobile do the buttons have a margin but on the web they do not?

**Note:** I know I can add padding/margin manually, set default button style, etc. I want to know why the default behaviour is different.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quite an interesting question. Thanks for asking.

This is basically due to the `ThemeData.materialTapTargetSize` parameter for the `MaterialApp`.

This feature decides what should be touchable dimensions of Material Button, in your case `ElevatedButton`.

The difference in behaviour is due to this piece of code in `flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart` at line no 377. `flutter sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

```
switch (platform) {
  case TargetPlatform.android:
  case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
  case TargetPlatform.iOS:
    materialTapTargetSize ??= MaterialTapTargetSize.padded;
    break;
  case TargetPlatform.linux:
  case TargetPlatform.macOS:
  case TargetPlatform.windows:
     materialTapTargetSize ??= MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap;
    break;
}
```

The `MaterialTapTargetSize.padded`, make buttons take a height of `48`. Whereas, the `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` does what it says and removes that constraint.

If you have your `MaterialApp` like this,

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap),
  home: CupertinoPickerExample(),
)
```

Then the out put is,

[image]

Comment: No. Thank you for asking. I have been learning flutter for the past month and I had wonderful time going through the documentation, all because of your question. Upvoted your question as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Nisanth Reddy's answer, you may also want to look at `visualDensity`, which is set also by `defaultTargetPlatform` [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L447), as a result of [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63788).

To ensure a consistent look across platfoms, I use the following -

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: ThemeData(
    ...
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
  ),
)
```